# How can I get a list of all accessible urls under a domain?

Tags: html, url, dns, web-crawler

I have a website at the domain [raymond.li](https://raymond.li). I want a comprehensive list of all urls, so I tried things like

```
wget -r --spider raymond.li
```

How to I get a comprehensive list of all accessible urls on a domain?

Edit: Upon further investigation, this is not possible.

Comment: If there is no link anywhere on your website to the specific URL you quote, then no crawler can find it, hence there is no solution. If you control the server side, and if you are using static pages, then you can list them on the server, but you will also need to take into account various webserver possible rewriting rules, aliases and so on. If you are using dynamic applications then it is even less possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a sitemap, which is basically an XML list of every URL on said domain. However, there is no general solution except crawling. Make sure to use robots.txt if you do use a crawler.